# How can I open Word file from google drive in user's browser with link to file

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

We try to give our users possibility to open and edit word file, strored in our Google Drive, with share link we issued. Our user's must not be asked to sign in, so we created google apps account to use server-to-server authentication (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

We are able to sign in with application's account and get "access_token". So how could any user open and edit word file from our Google Drive, having just the link to file ( for example: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zxmaAnls5DZMfEV0ByN_zTeaVx0RobmHidltvblsMrE/edit?usp=sharing ) ?

We tried to add "access_token" to the end of share uri: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zxmaAnls5DZMfEV0ByN_zTeaVx0RobmHidltvblsMrE/edit?usp=sharing&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}.

It seems it works, any could get access to our file without authentication, but after 2-3 seconds we see the following message: "You have been signed out. You must sign in again to save changes to this file."  http://savepic.net/6651295.htm

I noticed that with the share link, containing "access_token", obtained for our application, any user can open and edit file, but for the first 1-2 seconds only, then something happens and user see "You have been signed out. You must sign in again to save changes to this file."  All changes made during the first seconds after opening file are correctly saved.

We share file with options "Anyone with the link can edit".

And one more question: Is it possible to have google docs add-ons installed when user open our file?

I fail to find google explanation "how to", so please help :)

Comment: Google drive does not support this unless you share it that way (public write) in its share settings

Comment: Zig Mandel, file is shared as "Anyone with the link can edit file".

Comment: @ZigMandel Is there no way we can append an access token to a file sharing url from drive and make the file accessible without login or without making the file to be public ?

Comment: user must be logged in. anything else you might hack arround is likely against google drive terms of service.